# How to get class which invokes static method?

Tags: java, reflection

This is my code:

```
class A {

    public static void doIt() {
        //Class currentClass = new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
        //Class currentClass = MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass();
        String currentClass = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
        System.out.println("CALLING CLASS:" + currentClass);
    }
}

class B extends A { }

public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.doIt();
        B.doIt();
    }
}
```

As you see `doIt` method can be called by `A` and `B` classes. In `doIt` I want to know what class was used to call method (`A` or `B`). Is it possible? Three solutions I tried didn't work - it always says `A` class.

Comment: Define "didn't work". What was the output of each of your solutions?

Comment: What you're looking for isn't possible. Static methods don't work the way you want.

Comment: Some languages allow something like this - for example, `classmethod`s in Python - but not Java.

Comment: It should be possible with the Thread.currentThread() method somehow. I am quite sure I did that once for my own project but with a different setup - it was with static inner classes (singletons). But this is quite hacky anyway.

Comment: The only way would be to add `B.doIt()` which delegates the call to `A.doIt()`, and supplies some extra parameter to indicate it was called from `B`. But, I have to wonder: why do you need to know this?

Comment: You're probably doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought this is impossible as the java compiler can figure out which method will be called and emit the same instruction.

Turns out that it actually records the way the class is called.

So, the question now becomes:

- How do we get the place where the method is called?
- How do we use this information to get the way the method is called?

The first one is easy: We use a StackWalker, which can give us the [bytecode index](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.StackFrame.html#getByteCodeIndex%28%29).

Now we only need to parse the class, look at the instruction at that bytecode index, and figure out how this method was called.

I used ASM for that, but it might be the wrong tool here.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.lang.StackWalker.StackFrame;
import java.util.Set;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;

import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;

class CallingClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    private final StackFrame where;
    String ownerClass = null;

    public CallingClassVisitor(StackFrame where) {
        // We need a backing ClassWriter, so the Label is resolved.
        super(ASM8, new ClassWriter(0));
        this.where = where;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature,
            String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor parent = super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
        if (name.equals(where.getMethodName()) && descriptor.equals(where.getDescriptor())) {
            return new CallingMethodVisitor(where, parent);
        } else {
            return parent;
        }
    }

    class CallingMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

        private final StackFrame where;
        public CallingMethodVisitor(StackFrame where, MethodVisitor parent) {
            super(ASM8, parent);
            this.where = where;
        }

        @Override
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            visitLabel(lbl);
            if (lbl.getOffset() == where.getByteCodeIndex()) {
                ownerClass = owner; 
            }
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
        }
    }

    public String getOwnerClass() {
        return ownerClass;
    }
}



class A {

    static final StackWalker SW = StackWalker.getInstance(Set.of(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE));

    public static void doIt() {
        StackFrame sf = SW.walk(s -> s.skip(1).findFirst()).orElseThrow();
        InputStream source = sf.getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(sf.getClassName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
        try {
            CallingClassVisitor ccv = new CallingClassVisitor(sf);
            new ClassReader(source).accept(ccv, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
            String how = ccv.getOwnerClass();
            System.out.println(how);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }

    }
}

class B extends A { }

public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.doIt();
        B.doIt();
    }
}
```

In the end, I'm not sure if your requirement is worth that effort.

Comment: I quite enjoyed the challenge to find a way to do that. But seriously, don't use it.

Comment: I’d say, ASM is the right tool here, for the chosen approach. However, compared to the simple solution of adding a method with a similar signature to `B`, it’s overkill…

Comment: Javassist might be a better choice (the way I determine the bytecode index could be a bit fragile)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one here? I know its not exactly what you want but as others already stated ... you might want to rethink your design approach.

```
class A {
    protected static Class childClass; // alt. private

    // protected static Class getChildClass { return childClass; }

    public static void setChildClass(Class classReference) {
        childClass = classReference;
    }

    public static void doIt() {
        System.out.println("CLASS:" + childClass.getSimpleName());
    }
}

class B extends A { 

    // doIt() will be inherited

    // overloading method with a param
    public static void doIt(String message) {
        System.out.println("CLASS:" + B.class.getSimpleName() + ", message: " + message);
    }
}

public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.setChildClass(B.class);
        A.doIt(); // CLASS:B
        B.doIt(); // CLASS:B
        B.doIt("Hello") // CLASS:B, message: Hello
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You could have a simple controller and a few delegates to do something similar. Although its not all just static, you have alot more control over the parts. Please note that the example is very basic on purpose.

You could also have a class A and a class B and B has A as a dependency and then you just override what A (the delegate) should do differently. Also here ... its not static, but I do not think that this is your main problem. Its more the design after all.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final DoItController doItController = DoItController.Singleton.getInstance();
        doItController.doIt(DoerDelegateA.class);
        doItController.doIt(DoerDelegateB.class);
        doItController.doIt(DoerDelegateComplex.class);
    }
}

interface Doer {
    void doIt();
}

class DoItController {
    final Map<Class<? extends DoerDelegate>, DoerDelegate> doerDelegateMap;

    private DoItController() {
        doerDelegateMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        doerDelegateMap.put(DoerDelegateA.class, new DoerDelegateA());
        doerDelegateMap.put(DoerDelegateB.class, new DoerDelegateB());
        doerDelegateMap.put(DoerDelegateComplex.class, new DoerDelegateComplex());
    }

    public void doIt(Class<? extends DoerDelegate> delegateReference) {
        final DoerDelegate delegate = doerDelegateMap.getOrDefault(delegateReference, null);
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.doIt();
        }
    }

    public static class Singleton {
        private static DoItController instance;
        public static DoItController getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new DoItController();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}

class DoerDelegate implements Doer {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("Do something with: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}

class DoerDelegateA extends DoerDelegate {}
class DoerDelegateB extends DoerDelegate {}
class DoerDelegateComplex extends DoerDelegateA {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("Override standard method with: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

or ...

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final B b = new B();
        b.doIt();
    }
}

interface Doer {
    void doIt();
}

class A implements Doer {
    @Override
    public void doIt() { System.out.println("DO IT"); }
}

class B implements Doer {
    final A aDelegate;
    public B() {
        aDelegate = new A();
    }

    @Override
    public void doIt() {
        // standard
        aDelegate.doIt();
        // your specific B stuff
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pavel_K Either make the parentClass attribute protected (updated in the answer) or use a getter?

Comment: I know you just copied the question code, but "CALLING CLASS" is a misnomer, because the *calling* class is `NewMain`. The *called* class (aka target class) is `A` or `B`.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah. True that. Now it makes more sense. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The first code snippet looks like the simplest solution to the OP’s problem, except that this `setChildClass` thing has no actual purpose and the signature of `B.doIt` is inconsistent, having an additional `String message` parameter.

Comment: @Holger What do you mean with it has no purpose? The purpose of it is to have a setter on the base class where one can setup a reference to the child class. Why is it inconsistent? He asked for a method with a string in the comments, but deleted his comment. Anyway, `B.doIt` will be inherited from `A.doIt` - so that is just what I want here. Besides, OP did not reveal his true intensions for what he wants to do with the code - hard to work out something by just assuming intentions.

Comment: @Holger Well tbh its bad design anyway but everyone on this page already told the OP not to do it. With that in mind ... I don't know ... why would you delete a comment? Makes no sense. You are half right imo. Its a way to do it - its not the best way. There are other options and patterns, that would fit better - but all he asked for is a way to access the child class in the parent class. I disagree with you about the purpose - it does what it does. As I said - thats rather your opinion - but If you have a solution on your own I would love to see it. It is some kind of workaround here.

Comment: I just rechecked. The question is “**In `doIt` I want to know what class was used to call method (`A` or `B`).**” It never was something different. It never was “*a way to access the child class in the parent class*”. Making the call `A.doIt();` print “`CLASS:B`” is not even remotely matching that problem description.

Comment: @Holger I know. I see your point. But it depends on what he actually intends to do - doesn't it? If he knows the class (since he calls it somewhere) he could pass the reference as a param - maybe even to `doIt` - it depends on his architecture and code structure. In his example what does he want to do once he has the "calling class"? The only thing I see is the System.out.println() line. But you are technically right - its not the same thing as far as the intention goes (in my case its given - its just additional effort to provide the information).

Comment: I also thought about it being an xy-problem, which raised my confusion when I read your answer (as I didn’t know about the now-deleted comment). Just overriding the `doIt()` method in `B` and, e.g. delegating to a method in `A` with an additional `Class` argument would do the job of identifying that `B.doIt()` has been called and I thought, you were heading into that direction. Now I understand what I missed.

Comment: @Holger Yep. Lets be honest. The OP's question raises other unanswered questions. Its crucial how the stuff - at least thats my understanding - is implemented in order to give a precise answer.